# trying to add a TextView dynamically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a TextView widget dynamically in the code but it keeps crashing in the setText() line:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("YOU: " + ET_message.getText().toString()); //this line crashes
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);
ll.addView(tv);
```

does anybody know why? It's supposed to be the easiest line here.

**EDIT:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
           at com.guy_sh.messenger.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**EDIT #2: code change**

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(ET_message.getText())) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setText("YOU: " + ET_message.getText().toString());
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);
        ll.addView(tv);
    }
```

Comment: what is `ET_message` also post `Crash Log`

Comment: ET_messsage is the EditText from where i take the text from. and i dont know how to get the crash log.

Comment: check your logcat... also maybe your ET_message is null?

Comment: It's surely not null. I wrote into it.

Comment: so we need to see the crashlog under logcat tab

Comment: how do i get the crash report? every time it crashes the terminal says it cant give the crash report for a second and then writes a lot in the terminal without stopping

Comment: Assuming using AS then in monitor type search 'caused by' it will find the crash errors

Comment: The logcat error shows ET_message is null and not in the current scope. You appear to have declared it outside the scope of the current code. This is not a matter of ET_message not having text in it, it is a matter of the object not being accessible at this point in your code.

Comment: you can make a filter by error and in the query put "fatal" and is filter the crash log with the error

Comment: If the orginal EditText view is still available at this point in the code it might be worth trying just passing to another object and using that, so something like EditText newET_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ET_message);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace is telling you that `ET_message` is null. I see in the comments that you have said

> It's surely not null. I wrote into it.

It is important to understand the two following things can be true at the same time:

- There is some `EditText` visible in your activity that you can type into
- The variable named `ET_message` currently holds a `null` value

Locate the place where you assign a value to `ET_message` (probably a `findViewById()` call). Make sure that you're passing the right id, and that you're using an `android:id` attribute with that value in your `<EditText>` tag.